# How to disable default nginx site when using Chef and Vagrant?

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant

I am using Berkshelf, Chef and Vagrant and I am trying to configure a custom site running on nginx. I am using the opscode nginx recipe and then writing my own recipe for the custom site. When I run vagrant up I get the an error about not disabling the default nginx site. I've found several different suggestions but nothing seems to be working.

The error:

```
STDOUT:
STDERR: nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-    enabled/kyleboon.me:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My Berksfile:

```
site :opscode

metadata
cookbook 'nginx'
```

The 'roles/web.json' role I defined:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "description": "The base role for systems that serve HTTP traffic",
  "default_attributes": {
    "nginx": {
      "default_site_enabled": false
    },
    "app": {
      "name": "kyleboon.me",
      "web_dir": "/var/data/www/kyleboon.me"
    },
    "user":{
      "name": "vagrant"
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[nginx]",
    "recipe[kyleboon.me]"
  ]
}
```

Here is the recipes/default/default.rb for the nginx site I am adding:

```
nginx_site 'default' do
  action :disable
end

%w(public logs).each do |dir|
  directory "#{node.app.web_dir}/#{dir}" do
    owner node.user.name
    mode "0755"
    recursive true
  end
end

template "#{node.nginx.dir}/sites-available/kyleboon.me" do
  source "site.erb"
  mode 0777
  owner node.nginx.user
  group node.nginx.user
end

nginx_site "kyleboon.me"

cookbook_file "#{node.app.web_dir}/public/index.html" do
  source "index.html"
  mode 0755
  owner node.user.name
end
```

(P.S. I know the file permissions need to be changed, I've just been fiddling with lots of things, I'll update those once I get everything else working)

And here is attributes/default.rb:

```
override['nginx']['enable_default_site'] = false
```

You can see I have tried to disable the default site in the web.json, the attributes and the recipe itself but none of them stick.

I don't have a node or solo node defined and I'm not sure if that's an issue. My main problem with vagrant so far has been the endless possibilities for how to do things. No two examples are done in the same way and I'm not sure what is considered the 'best' or 'right' way to go.

Comment: I found that disabling the default site via `node['nginx']['enable_default_site']` usually works - maybe you have a symlink left over in sites-enabled from previous runs that is not managed by chef anymore (Chef does not delete things just because you remove a resource declaration)?

Comment: I've done a vagrant destroy to make sure. It definitely seems to be creating the link in sites-enabled each time I provision but I wil double check.

Comment: I think the answer by Cliff Erson is correct. Maybe you want to accept it?

Comment: Hopefully I can ask a question.  What does it mean to disable the default site?  Does that means requests that don't map to a defined site go to the first site, as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable any nginx site by name using the nginx_site and its name. The problem you are having is because the nginx_site [definition](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx/blob/master/definitions/nginx_site.rb#L21) is actually looking for the enable parameter to be set to true or false not the action parameter set to :disabled.

To disable the default site add to your recipe:

```
nginx_site 'default' do
  enable false
end
```

This is working for me as of version 1.7.1 of the nginx opscode cookbook. I dont know if this will work with the version provided by community as it appears to be several months old.

To get the latest version add to your Berksfile:

```
cookbook 'nginx', git: 'https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx'
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Perfect, even in 2016.

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting the same error, but I don't have the default site enabled. Instead, it's coming from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`!  I had to resort to

```
file "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" do
  action :delete
end
```

This is coming from the RHEL package that the nginx cookbook is installing on my box.

Comment: I think this is because at the end of the nginx.conf.erb are two lines, one of which includes conf.d/*.conf and the other includes /sites-enabled/*. I'm pretty sure this means that disabling default won't work because even though you haven't created the symlink in sites-enabled, it will still show up from conf.d

Comment: This error is now sorted in Nginx ~-> 2.7.6, https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/blob/master/recipes/commons_dir.rb#L51