# nginx allowing any unspecified sub-domain without error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with Passenger and Nginx Support.  I have successfully setup my server to run my Ghost.org blog from the root,but the one thing I cannot figure out is why subdomains are allowed...for example.  If you go to http://studiorooster.com you will get my site, but if you enter http://anything_here.studiorooster.com you get the Nginx welcome/success page.  I have racked my brain and searched the forums, but I don't even know how to ask my question to get the answer I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a configuration issue. You need to define a default server in your conf file (above any other server locations) to handle any domains or sub domains that will resolve to your webserver.

See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name/9826635#9826635) for more details

Comment: Thank you, the link you provided made sense.  Thank you again.

@hongli thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

That's how the `server_name` directive in Nginx works. Requests only match `server` blocks for which the `server_name` match. All requests that don't match any `server_name`, go to the first `server` block in the configuration file.

You can force a `server` block to match all host names by setting `server_name _`. See the Nginx documentation.