# Catch all non-handled requests with HTTP 200 + static file

Tags: nginx

I am trying to catch all traffic not caught by a sites-enabled configuration file, and instead of throwing the default 404, to instead throw a 200 with a blank response instead.

So, for example, if my site is https://www.example.com at ip `x.x.x.x` and somebody maps https://www.bad.com to my ip at `x.x.x.x` they would simply get a 200 with a blank content.

To accomplish this, I have a file located at `/var/www/index.html` that is a blank file, and have the following rule set up in `{nginxdir}/conf.d/200catchall.conf` which is imported in the standard {nginxdir}/nginx.conf file:

```
# Serve blank page to any requests not intended for one of our servers
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name _;
       location / {
                root /var/www
       }
}
```

This works great for rendering the 200 blank screen for a request to https://www.bad.com. However, it tries to traverse the directory when something like https://www.bad.com/cgibin/nofile.php is requested, and ends up throwing an error to error.log and results ultimately in a 404.

I've also attempted to replace the `root` directive with a `try_files /var/www/index.html` directive, which seems to give the same result...

Have been pulling my hair out for a while on this - any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid sending any content back, minimal load for your server, return a `204 No Content` response instead. See [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#204).

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  return 204;
}
```

An alternative approach to setting up a catch all server is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name/9826635#9826635).

Comment: This is what ultimately helped me.  I'm using a 204 for all requests that aren't intended for my server.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest catch-all looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  return 200;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alexey...problem is that if I get a request for most file formats other than *.html (e.g. `https://www.bad.com/flarg/blarf.zip`), the browser actually downloads the response as that filetype, rather than rendering a blank html page...any advice?