# Nginx - Wordpress multisite. Redirect non-www to www

Tags: nginx, http-redirect, wordpress

On a Ubuntu VPS I am running Wordpress Multisite with nginx.

How can I redirect all sites-domains from non-www to www?

**I want this to be done not site by site, but with a rule for every site after created** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up all your domains server blocks in Nginx with `wwww`. That is, only set up  `http://www.example.com` etc type server blocks and then create a separate catch all server block to redirect all `http://example.com` etc type requests to `http://www.example.com` etc.

This is based on the configuration [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name/9826635#9826635)

```
http {
    [...]
    # Catch All for http://example.com domains
    # These will all redirect to http://www.example.com
    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 http://www.$host$request_uri;
    }
    # Other server blocks (http://www.example.com etc)
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

The way this will work is that all requests for http://example.com will always only be served by the catch all block which will bounce them to http://www.example.com.

Caveats are:

1. Make sure you do not use the `default_server` directive anywhere.
2. Requests for domains that resolve to your server but are not specifically defined, will return a redirect loop error to the user. To avoid this, if an issue, ensure that every domain that resolves to the server is defined.