# Why sometimes I can't browse a website by directly using it's ip from ping?

Tags: dns, web, ip, ping

The website I want to go is pixiv.net, and after I ping it I found out it's ip, which is 210.129.120.44, but if I directly putting this ip as address in a browser, I got a access forbidden. But I can visit pixiv.net. And then I tried to bind this ip with pixiv.net in my host file. I can still get access to pixiv.net.

Comment: I also want to know how to brows pixiv via ip address, can I change my http request header or something in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The web server at that location is probably configured to respond to a fully qualified domain name that it routes to a directory of HTML pages and other assets. It’s likely there is no configuration for requests to its root IP address.

Comment: So how does it work in dns when I write address as pixiv.net in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely one of the following two,

1. The nginx web server at that IP could be configured only to allow access via the domain name. [prevent access via IP on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104943/how-to-disable-direct-access-to-a-web-site-by-ip-address)
2. The nginx server could be a reverse proxy which re-routes requests to the true web server. [nginx as a reverse proxy server](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)