# Why is the Gitlab instance accessible from multiple subdomains?

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab, toran-proxy

I have a ubuntu 14.04 server on Digital Ocean where I am running a Gitlab instance, which is accessible from `repo.mydomain.com`
I want to set up a [toran](https://toranproxy.com/) instance, which must be accessible from `toran.mydomain.com`

***However, I noticed that for every subdomain that points to the server, shows the Gitlab login page. Thus, when I browse to toran.mydomain.com or even test.mydomain.com it shows the Gitlab page. How can I fix this?***

### Gitlab configuration

I've modified some of the gitlab original configuration, an important modification is the use of my 'own' nginx instance in stead of the build in instance, following [this guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/doc/settings/nginx.md).

My gitlab configuration (I used dummy values) is as follows:

```
external_url 'http://repo.mydomain.com'

 gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'emailhere'
 gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'Gitlab'

 gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = "postgresql"
 gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = "unicode"
 gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "thdbname"
# gitlab_rails['db_pool'] = 10
 gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "theuser"
 gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "thepass"
 gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "localhost"
 gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 1337

 gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
 gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.mandrillapp.com"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
 gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "emailhere"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "ojojowij"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "domainhere"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true

 postgresql['enable'] = false

 web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']

 nginx['enable'] = false
```

The nginx configuration for gitlab is as follows:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name repo.mydomain.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log error;

  # Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
  passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

  # Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
  passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

  # Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
  # prevent permission issues
  passenger_user git;
  passenger_group git;

  # Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 1;

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

### Toran configuration

```
 server {
    #listen 8000;
    listen *:8000;
    server_name toran.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/toran/web;
    #index index.html index.htm;

    access_log  /var/log/toran/nginx/toran_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/toran/nginx/toran_error.log error;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Gitlab, but its more of Nginx related. Please see this answer: [Why is nginx responding to any domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name)

Answer (score 0):

Make Toran server block listen port 80:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  ...
}
```