# Nginx restrict domains

Tags: nginx

Please find the below setting which is placed in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled** under my site domain name. (mysite.lk)

```
server {  
   listen   80;
   server_name mysite.lk www.mysite.lk;

   location / {  
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
   }

}
```

The application is running on port 8080 and here I'm redirecting all the 80 traffic to 8080.
My website only uses **mysite.lk** and **www.mysite.lk** domain names.

Hence, I want to **restrict/block all other domains** (except mysite.lk and www.mysite.lk) which are coming to this server IP. What is the change that I need to do to achieve this?

I tried numerous things such as answers given in the 
[Why is nginx responding to any domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name), but was getting errors at the nginx startup.

Please help me out!
Thanks.

### **Update**

Found the Answer. A catch-all server block should needed in the top of the config before the given config like below. The code block should be like this.

```
server {
    return 403;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name mysite.lk www.mysite.lk;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
   }

}
```

Comment: You need a *catch-all* server. Your linked answer shows the solution. If you are getting errors in your implementation - you need to fix them. Start at the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. Are there any other `server` blocks already defined in your system - use `nginx -T` to see the full picture.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was an error in the server block. Also adding catch-all block "server {   return 403; }" before the given block is restricting all other domains.

Comment: It works with port 80 but not with 443. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Yeah it works with port 80 but not with 443, why??

Comment: @Kornikopic Did you found any workaround?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first server defined in Nginx is treated as the `default_server` so by just adding one as the default and returning 412 (Precondition Failed) or any another status that best fits your requirements, will help for the subsequent servers to obey the `server_name`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 412;
} 

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name mysite.lk www.mysite.lk;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
   }
}
```

Comment: You missed a semi-colon after `return 412`, other than that, worked great for me.

Answer (score 13):

All of the above answers are correct. But they all don't work if the other domain tries to access your host via port 443(https/SSL).

To Block access to https requests just add an if block in the https server configuration of your host.

```
server {

    server_name www.xyz.com xyz.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = "www.specificdomainyouwanttoblock.com") {
        return 404;
    }

    if ($host = "specificdomainyouwanttoblock.com") {
        return 404;
    }

    # or you can simply add:

    if ($host != "yourdomain.com") {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want to account for subdomains in the host checking clause you need to use regex. So something like `$host !~* "\.domain\.com$"` (ends with .domain.com)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a server directive without server_name. Something like this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

EDIT
Please read http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
In short nginx always looks for best match when it comes to server_names or locations and if it fails to find one it uses the default server.

Comment: I had a look at that as well. I want to deny all domains except mysite.lk and www.mysite.lk. And also the traffic must redirect to 8080 port as well.

Comment: Yes I understand. This piece of config right next to your config will do exactly that

Comment: Fount it! Please find the updated answer in the question section. Thanks for the quick support as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a player script with a Firewall that blocks the websites that are not on my whitelist but it turns out that if I have the Firewall activated, the videos stop working in my Android application, they know how I can modify my Firewall to work with package names Android applications to add my application to the white list and be able to play videos in my app with the Firewall active since I must have it disabled to be able to play the videos in my application.

```
/**
 * Disable access baseed on referer
 */
if (Data::Get("accs_restriction") == "enable") {
    $domains = explode(",", Data::Get("allowed_domains"));
    $referer = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], PHP_URL_HOST);
    if (empty($referer) || !in_array($referer, $domains)) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        require TEMPLATES . "pages/access_denied.php";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the following lines in site's virtual host file:

```
if ($http_referer ~* (example\.com)) {
    return 403;
}
```

It's working for me.