# Using nginx reverse proxy, how do you BLOCK all request except if request comes from my application

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm actually new to nginx. I was trying to create a reverse proxy using nginx for my rest api.

Here's my setup:

I have a server, for the benefit of labelling, we shall call as **myserver** with domain name **myserver.com**.

Now, my **Backend REST API (which is written in Django)** resides in **myserver**, which is run via docker (internally, **backend-api:8000**). I created a reverse proxy that interfaces with this backend server and I created a subdomain for this (**subdomain.myserver.com**) that actually just points to **backend-api:8000**.

Now, I also have a **frontend app (written in PHP)** which actually is also deployed in the same server (**myserver**) and is also hosted via docker.
I then have a separate domain name for this (say, **frontend.com**) that just points to the directory of the frontend PHP files in **myserver**.

Now, I am looking for a way to block all other requests except if it comes from my application only (from **frontend.com**). I tried adding the if *($host != **"frontend.com"**) {return 404}* but when I tested it, my **frontend.com** receives a 404 message when I try to connect to the backend. I also tried using allow directive, but still no avail.

Here is my default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    
    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass backend-api:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000 always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml application/json text/xml text/css text;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;

    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to block requests by ip (for example 192.168.100.100):

```
location / {
    allow 192.168.100.100;
    deny all;
    uwsgi_pass backend-api:8000;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
}
```

Or you can check `$remote_addr`

```
if ($remote_addr != 192.168.100.100) {
   return 403;
   break;
}
```

Checking `$host != "frontend.com"` won't work because it check request parameter HOST and doesn't have anything with your current host.

Comment: I actually have tried using the IP of **myserver**, but it blocks everything now, which unfortunately includes request coming from my application.. Is there a way to print or echo the IP's?

Comment: @c0mpumast3r As you use docker containers you need to use their ip addresses. All requests' ips you can see in access_log file - add `access_log /path/to/log;` string in your config

Comment: Yeah but hmmmn, my frontend app is actually hosted directly from my server.. its not run thru docker.. my backend (nginx proxy, django app and db) are run via docker though..

Comment: also, when I tried putting the IP address of docker, all requests are not blocked.. even from postman.. but when I put the IP address of **myserver** only, all requests are blocked (frontend app and also postman).. it should be that the frontend app should only be accepted..

Comment: I think if only I could find a way to get the real client IP and block this IP from nginx, this should have been the solution.. I just dont know how to get the real client IP because its the docker IP thats get obtained from $remote_addr

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved it already. I added the one highlighted below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name **subdomain.myserver.com**;
    
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                    
                    
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
                    
    allow **ip_address_of_myserver**;
    deny all;
    
        
    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    
        uwsgi_pass backend-api:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000 always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml application/json text/xml text/css text;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;

    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;

}
```

This works actually. The application only caters to requests coming from myserver and not from any other computer/server such as from postman. Anyway, if anyone, have a comment/suggestion on this to improve, please let me know. Thank you.