# Nginx regex variable for vhost is null

Tags: regex, nginx, vhosts

I have a config file that look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]+).(?<user>[^.]+).example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/htdocs;
...
}
```

so i can access to the site with a url like test.user.example.com.

In one server the config file is working as expected but in other server the variables are void.

Any idea ?

Comment: Just FYI: to match dots, you need to escape them when outside of a character class, `^(?<folder>[^.]+)\.(?<user>[^.]+)\.example\.com`

Comment: One of your server blocks will be the *default server* and will process requests even if the host name does not match the regular expression - which will mean that the variables will be void. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to modify the regex from

```
server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]+)\.(?<user>[^.]+).example.com;
```

to

```
server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]*).(?<user>[^.]*).example.com;
```