# PHP - Prevent site mirroring

Tags: php

There are people who like to mirror sites by pointing domain probably and waste the bandwidth from the server, so I want to redirect mirrored users to the real one

I tried with...

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.example.com')
{
  header('Location: http://www.example.com');
  exit;
}
```

...but the problem is that some people use **`str_replace`** to fight this.

Then **`www.example.com`** part becomes same as their mirror site, hence it's the same as **`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`** and it won't work.

Comment: If you set up the web server properly, it should pass through requests that has the hostnames you've configured. Then those request won't even reach your PHP-application.. How to do that depends on the environment and what web server you're using.

Comment: I have setup nginx to listen only to cloudflare IP addresses and blocked everything else via iptables

Comment: Sure, but you should also configure [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) with the hostnames you want to allow. Then you can create a vhost without a server name, which will act as a honey-pot for other requests. That can simply return 404

Comment: Exactly like that. `listen custom_port ssl http2;
 server_name www.example.com;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is nginx responding to any domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name)

Comment: ^ That shows how you can do what I suggested in my second comment.

Comment: A site mirror redirecting to the original site kind of loses it's point as a mirror since if the original site is down the mirror will be down as well

Comment: I actually tried with server `server { return 404; }` to the first block, but the mirror is still mirroring it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache you can add a *.htacess* file into your web-root folder that does the work for you. The advantage of this is that if you want to test locally you can change that specific file.

Here is a example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```

Comment: Hi, I am using nginx

Comment: i don't have much experience with nginx but this is what if found after a quick google search https://serverfault.com/questions/832456/nginx-redirect-based-on-domain-name