# Block/Deny all requests that are not mapped by locations

Tags: http, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Currently I'm using nginx as a proxy server to multiple docker containers running in different hosts.

Each container or pair of containers is mapped using a location block in a virtual hosts file, like this `dev.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name dev.mydomain.xyz

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.16.18.2:8080/dashboard
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://172.16.18.2:5000/api
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    ...
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mydomain.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mydomain.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

    if ($host = dev.mydomain.xyz) {

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        server_name dev.mydomain.xyz;
        listen 80;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

What I would expect of this setup is that if I request a url like: `https://dev.mydomain.xyz/aaaaaa` it would give me a 404, but instead what is happening is that it is solving to the root block (the first `location /` block).

What I want to achieve now, for security and usability reasons is to block/deny all requests that are made in the aforementioned way (location block nonexistent/not listed). I saw this question: [about a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name), but that didn't work as I would expect. Bear in mind that I am using multiple virtual hosts file, all being included by `nginx.conf`.

Example:

```
Request to dev.mydomain.xyz/api is allowed and processed
Request to dev.mydomain.xyz/nothing is denied
```

Nginx is version `nginx/1.14.2`, installed in a `Debian 10 x64` bit. Let me know if there's any additional info needed. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**
To be clear, by wanted requests I meant the location I have mapped for a given virtual host (it's endpoints), of which each of this locations must be proxied for a different container. So like, requests to `/` must go to `container1`, requests to `/api` must go to `container2`, etc.

Comment: Interesting, is there any way I could use some kind of regex to deny the unwanted requests.

Comment: My accepted requests would be the locations I have mapped (`/`, `/api`, `/database` for example). Thing is, each of those routes must be proxied to a different container. I'll add this information to the post.

Comment: Your locations accept URIs that **begin with** `/api` and as I said, `location /` accepts URIs that **begin with** `/` (which is everything else). If you want to just process the `/`, `/api` and `/database` URI, use the `=` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I looked up this part of the docs and it didn't looked like what I wanted to do. Could you post a proper answer so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location / { ... }` block is the default location and used to process any requests that do not match any other more specific `location` statement. The rules for `location` processing is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

The `location /api { ... }` block is a *prefix location* that matches any URI that **begins with** `/api`.

If you want to only proxy the specific URIs `/` and `/api`, then use the `location` directive with an `=` operator. For example:

```
location / {
    return 403;
}
location = / {
    # proxy for only /
}
location = /api {
    # proxy for only /api
}
```

The above will return a "Forbidden" status code for any URI except `/` and `/api`.

However, a very strict approach will not work for most applications, as there are generally a multiutde of resource files (e.g. `*.css`, `*.js`) with unique URIs that also need to be handled by the server or its upstream proxies.

Comment: TY again for the answer.